# How to parse data from local JSON file to the labels in table view cell using swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, uitableview, parsing

Need some help with parsing data to the labels in table view cell. I have a local JSON file:

```
"""
{
    "data": [
        {
            "loops": [
                {
                    "name": "Away we go",
                    "producer": "Tubular Kingz",
                    "count": "28",
                    "genre": "Lo-fi Hip Hop"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Test",
                    "producer": "Testing",
                    "count": "25",
                    "genre": "Lo-fi"
                }
            ],
            "beatloops": [
                {
                    "name" : "Alien",
                    "instrument" :"Arp",
                    "songName" : "alienarpjason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Big Brake",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "BigBrake_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Bongo Beats",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "BongoBeats_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Dreaming",
                    "instrument" :"Keys",
                    "songName" : "Dreaming_Keys_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Funky Groove",
                    "instrument" :"Bass",
                    "songName" : "FunkyGroove_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Futurist",
                    "instrument" :"Arp",
                    "songName" : "Futurist_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Hoping for change",
                    "instrument" :"Arp",
                    "songName" : "HopingForChange_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Manic",
                    "instrument" :"Bass",
                    "songName" : "Manic_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Sassy",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "Sassy_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Serious",
                    "instrument" :"Arp",
                    "songName" : "Serious_Arp_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Stable Bricks",
                    "instrument" :"Bass",
                    "songName" : "StableBrick_Bass_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Thump",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "Thump_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Tropic",
                    "instrument" :"Drums",
                    "songName" : "TropicVibe_Drums_Jason.mp3",
                    "producer" : "Stefan Guy"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"""
```

Model File:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct BeatData: Decodable {
    let data: [BeatPackData]
}

struct BeatPackData: Decodable {
    let loops: [Loop]
    let beatloops: [BeatLoop]
}

struct BeatLoop: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let instrument: String
    let songName: String
    let producer: String
}

struct Loop: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let producer: String
    let count: String
    let genre: String
}
```

Data Loader:

```
public class DataLoader {
    @Published var beatData = [BeatData]()
    
    init() {
        parseJSON()
    }
//        load()
        //        loadLoops()
        //    }
        //
        
        func parseJSON() {
            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beatpackdata", ofType: "json") else {
                print("\n-------> bundle path error")
                return
            }
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            
            do {
                let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(BeatData.self, from: jsonData)
                print("\n-------> response: \(response)")
            }
            catch {
                print("\n====> error: \(error)" )
            }
            return
        }
    }
```

My TableView:

```
extension BeatPackViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomLoopsCell = beatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstLoopCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomLoopsCell
        gettingSongName()
        cell.loopNameLabel.text = dataNew[indexPath.row].data[indexPath.row].beatloops[indexPath.row].name
//        cell.loopNameLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].beatpackdata[indexPath.row].loopsdictionary![indexPath.section].nameOfLoop
//        cell.producerLabel.text = beatPackData?.beatpackdata[indexPath.section].beatloopsdictionary[indexPath.row].producer
//        cell.instrumentLabel.text = beatPackData?.beatpackdata[indexPath.section].beatloopsdictionary[indexPath.row].instrument
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.selectionStyle = .none        
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
//        cell.playButtonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
        
        if let playingCell = currentPlayingIndex, playingCell == indexPath.row {
            cell.playButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause.png"), for:
                                            .normal)
        } else {
            cell.playButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "playBtn.png"), for:
                                            .normal)
        }
    return cell
}
```

Maybe some problems with parsing data or something else. When I've tried to load data to the labels, I've got error "Index out of range" Also need to make the return of cells, that it should be count of beat loops in json file.

Comment: You can’t hardcode the number of rows in tableview(numberOfRowsInSection), return the actual value instead. And you can’t reuse indexPath for sub arrays, `dataNew[indexPath.row].data[indexPath.row].beatloops[indexPath.row].name`, it’s only valid for the main array

Comment: Are you displaying just `loops` or `beatloops`?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You don't assign the result to the data source array and you return 1 in `numberOfSections` but use the section part of the index path in `cellForRow`. It's unclear what you want to display.

Comment: At this view controller only beat loops

Answer (score 0):

This part: `.data[indexPath.row]` looks wrong. You only have 1 element in `data` from your JSON, so when you try get an element from an index of greater than 1, you get an 'index out of range' error.

I don't know exactly what `dataNew` is, but I suspect it is a similar situation with that as well. Instead, use the following:

```
cell.loopNameLabel.text = dataNew[0].data[0].beatloops[indexPath.row].name
```

Also: don't hard-code the number of rows in a section, as the JSON may change. Instead, get the number of rows from `dataNew[0].data[0].beatloops.count`.

---

Your JSON file should not have `"""` at the top and bottom of the file. This is invalid JSON.

Comment: Still index out of range, maybe problem with parsing data?

Comment: @mozeX We can't see what `dataNew` is, so could be an issue with that. Try split the code up onto multiple lines (so you know which crashes) and print `dataNew`.

Comment: It's this, I've input this in view controller - let dataNew = DataLoader().beatData. We getting this from my model, just check on the top.

Comment: @mozeX Ok. `beatData` should not be an array anyway, since you are decoding to only get a single element. That would also mean `dataNew` is now an array, so you would just have `dataNew.data[0].beatloops[indexPath.row].name`. Most importantly, which line still gives you the error?

Comment: I think I've got an error, because problem with parsing, because when I try to print the data, it shows empty arrays

Comment: @mozeX Try `print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8))` to see what the JSON is from the file, to make sure it has been fetched properly

Comment: Got this []
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]

Comment: @mozeX Assuming those `"""` at the top and bottom of your JSON file aren't there (otherwise you would get an invalid JSON error), is there more to your JSON file?

Comment: You mean this """ shouldn't be there?

Comment: @mozeX No they shouldn't be there. I tried the code and got an error on the `print("\n====> error: \(error)" )` line, otherwise it worked.

Comment: Now I've got printed data, but how to make it correct to the labels, because now I've put all code inside the view controller

Comment: @mozeX If you are no longer having a crash and it's now about the layout of the labels, that's a different question. But if my answer helped, an accept & upvote would be appreciated!

Comment: It's this question, just check how question named